# Angular method parameter strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple component with a child component(modal).

**parentComponent.ts**

```
onShowModal($e) {
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage(AppConsts.chromeExtension.id, {}, (reply) => 
            { 
                const isInstalled = reply ? true : false; // here is true
                this._service.getById(id) 
                    .subscribe(response => {
                        this.customModal.show($e, response, isInstalled);
                    });
           });
 }
```

**customModalComponent.ts**

```
  // Component Code
  isExtensionInstalled = false;

   show(event, response, isInstalled: boolean) {
      this.isExtensionInstalled = isInstalled;
      this.response = response;
      this.event = event;

      this.modal.show(); //Here the modal appears on the screen, but the `this.isExtensionInstalled` variable stays as false for a while, then it changes to true (after some milliseconds);
  }
```

The problem is that when i execute the `onShowModal` method, the `isInstalled` constant is true, So it is `true` the isInstalled parameter. But when the modal actually appears on the screen the `isExtensionInstalled` stays false for a while, then it changes to the correct value passed in the parameter (true).

Why is it happening?

Comment: Is it possible that the code is running outside of the Angular zone?

Comment: the `chrome.runtime.sendMassage` method i think.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the code inside that method in a `zone.run()`? https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone

Comment: not yet, ill try that.